# python 2 dictionaries into 1 dictionary join based on their values

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the situation
I have 2 dictionaries as

```
dict1
{ 
  D1K1: (v1, v2),
  D1K2: (v3, v4)
}

dict2
{ 
  D2K1: (v1, v2),
  D2K2: (v3, v4)
}
```

I need to merge/join them based on their values as join condition. so the final output should look like

```
{
  D1K1: D2K1,
  D1K2: D2K2
}
```

What's the best way to achieve this in python?

Comment: What happens to asymmetric values?

Comment: did you have try any thing already ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
dict1 = { 
  'D1K1': ('v1', 'v2'),
  'D1K2': ('v3', 'v4')
}

dict2 = { 
  'D2K1': ('v1', 'v2'),
  'D2K2': ('v3', 'v4')
}

# reverse dict2. this randomly chooses one of the possible mappings
# if there are more than one key with the same value..
inv2 = dict((v, k) for k, v in dict2.items())

# this assumes that there will always be a reverse mapping in dict2 
# for all values in dict1 (use inv2.get(v, default_value) if that is
# not the case).
print dict((k, inv2[v]) for k, v in dict1.items())
```

Comment: If two values are same in `dict2`, swapping keys/values will causes one of them getting deleted.

Comment: Nothing is deleted from dict2, but you're correct, it randomly chooses one possible mapping in cases where there are more than one possibility. The OP didn't have any such elements in his example though, so I'm not sure that is relevant here..?

Comment: the values are distinct as well

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I came up with

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
# create joint list of key-values, and sort it by values
dicts_merged = sorted(chain(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()), key=itemgetter(1))

# Rearrange by values
grouped_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in dicts_merged:
    grouped_dict[val].append(key)

# Final step
result = {v[0] : v[1] for v in grouped_dict if len[v] >= 2}
```